# IOS Push Notification count

Tags: ios, push-notification

I need to display push notification count. when user launches the application by tapping application or from notification bar.

Example: application is in background and device received 10 notifications related to my app. we have to display notification count 10 within app.

I can achieve this by adding content-update key in notification payload. But I don't want to make change in notification payload.

Comment: you need to make changes in payload because application does not know that push is come till user clicked on that notification so it is not possible at application side

Answer (score 0):

Your backend need to send bagdes for this :- Eaxmple 
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}

and you can use this badges in your apps.

Comment: I don't want to make any change from backend side.

Comment: {"aps":{"alert":"A problem has been detected with your vehicle. Identified as:Rough Road Sensor 'A' Signal Circuit.","badge":1,"sound":"default","},"payload":"{\"EventID\":\"DTCStored\"}","channelIdentifier":"FCM"}

Comment: All the push notification count are come form badges from back end side,

Comment: Or you can add in your app application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10 for badges as well.

Comment: We have deferent-deferent type of notification. basic of type we have to show notification count. badge always will be same. this is not a solution.

Comment: For this you can use local database to manage the count like "core data" or "sqlite" for count increment  , to show the application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10

Comment: How we get know how many notification we received when application in background. that is my question.

Comment: If your application is running in the background your appDelegate's didReceiveRemoteNotification method gets called there you can do your task. But if your app is suspended or user quits forcefully you don't get callback.

Comment: if application in background none of apns delegate method will call. if  added  "content-update": 1 in APNS payload.  that case  didReceiveRemoteNotification method will call.

Answer (score 0):

You can check how many notifications were received (assuming you are incrementing badges in your push notifications) by checking `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber`.

This also assumed you reset the badge count each time they leave the app (standard practice), if for some reason you don't though, simply save [via NSUserDefaults] the current badge count in the willResignActive callback and check the delta when they return.